# Can I get OwnerDrawLabelProvider to draw outside of the cell?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a Jface TableViewer in my Eclipse RCP app whose columns are all drawn by OwnerDrawLabelProviders. My cells are now all being drawn the way that I want, but I'm unable to use an OwnerDrawLabelProvider to draw anything outside of the current cell being drawn.

I've illustrated the problem below. If the cell with the green background is being drawn, and I attempt to draw a red line across the entire table, the red line stops being drawn as soon as I exit the cell.

[image]

I thought that what was happening here is that the other cells were drawing over the top of the red line, but I showed this wasn't the case by deactivating the paint(), measure(), and erase() methods for the next column. Instead, I think what's happening is that the Table is hiding my red line in a lower display layer as soon as it leaves the cell.

Is there any way to draw outside the cell with an OwnerDrawLabelProvider? I have a workaround, namely issuing the same draw command in each cell that would be drawn in, but that's pretty ugly and could potentially lead to performance problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GC` that is passed to the paint/measure/erase methods has the clipping area set to just the current cell. Any drawing operation you do on the GC that is outside of the clipping area is ignored.

You could try calling the `GC.setClipping` method to change the clipping area but you may still have problems with things being overwritten.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for! I tested it out and it works exactly how I expected. I do have to watch out not to overwrite it with the rest of my custom drawing methods, but I figure that's par for the course. Thanks!